# Is strongly elliptic operator necessarily properly elliptic?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-operators, elliptic-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

Let us consider
$$
A(D)u:=\sum_{|p|\leq l} a_p D^p u, 
$$
where $a_p$ may be complex, and define
$$
A_0(\xi)= \sum_{|p|=l} a_p \xi^p 
$$

> **Def 1**. The operator $A$ is called strongly elliptic if
> $$
> A_0(\xi)\neq 0 \quad \forall\, \xi\in  \mathbb{R}^n \,\,\text{with}\,\,\xi\neq 0.  
> $$

> **Def 2**. The operator defined above with
> $l=2m$ is said to be properly elliptic if
> it is elliptic and if for any
> linearly independent $\xi$ and $\xi'\in \mathbb{R}^n$ belonging to $ \mathbb{R}^n$, the polynomial
> $A_0(\xi+\tau \xi')$ in the complex number $\tau$ has
> $m$ roots with positive imaginary part.
> **Def 3**. The operator defined above with
> $l=2m$ is said to be strongly elliptic if
> there exists a  complex number $\gamma$ and
> a positive constant $\alpha$ such that
> $$
> \Re (\gamma A_0(\xi))\geq \alpha |\xi|^{2m} \,\,\,\,\forall\, \xi\in  \mathbb{R}^n. 
> $$

Obviously, strongly elliptic is elliptic. If $n>2$, then we can find any elliptic operator that is properly elliptic. Is a strongly elliptic operator necessarily properly elliptic?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to attack it. For the case $n>2$, you know that it is easy. If $n>2$, then we can pass continuously from $A(\xi+\tau \xi')$ into $A(-\xi+\tau \xi')$, because the set 
$\{\xi\in \mathbb{R}^n; \xi\not\in \{\mathbb{R}\xi_0\}\}$ is connected. Under such passage, we know that the numbers of roots in the upper and the lower half-plane are preserved, and these numbers are equal.

For the case $n=2$, let us add one dimension. Let us consider 
$$
B_0:=A_0(\xi)+ \lambda^{2m} i  
$$
Then $B_0$ is elliptic and hence it is properly elliptic, since now the dimension is large than 0.  Indeed, if $B_0(\xi_0,\lambda_0)=0$, then we have $\Re A_0(\xi_0,\lambda_0)=\Re B_0(\xi_0,\lambda_0)=0$, which implies that $\xi_0=0$. Then we have $B_0(\xi_0,\lambda_0)=i\lambda_0^p=0$.